# Promote particular user's Apache VirtualHost to default

Tags: apache, cpanel, virtualhost, whm

As documented by Apache under [Using Name-based Virtual Hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html#using):

> If no matching virtual host is found, then **the first listed virtual host** that matches the IP address will be used.
>
> As a consequence, the first listed virtual host is the *default* virtual host.

Currently, the template at `/var/cpanel/templates/apache2_4/main.default` generates such a default VirtualHost (per IP address) with `DocumentRoot [% serverroot %]/htdocs`.

We would instead like the `VirtualHost` that is generated for a particular user to be that default.  What is the best/recommended way of accomplishing this?

My current thinking is to place the user's (compiled) `VirtualHost` directive in `/usr/local/apache/conf/includes/pre_virtualhost_2.conf`, but this obviously won't be managed by WHM should the user's configuration change.

Is there a better way?

Comment: I've just tried `ServerAlias *` and brutally discovered that this directive matches **really** anything, including previous declared virtualhosts. For a second I thought it was working!

Comment: "We would instead like the VirtualHost that is generated for a particular user to be that default". How is the request linkable to the "user"? So your saying you have HTTP requests coming for URL domains that don't have virtual hosts, and you want them to be routed to a particular user? So you must have user 1to1 with IP address right? Otherwise doesn't make sense.

Comment: @S.Pinkus: How does it not make sense?  I want all web requests, regardless of hostname (unless overridden by a more specific rule), to be routed to a particular user.  Seems pretty straightforward to me!  Indeed, that's exactly what the quote from the Apache documentation describes.

Comment: I was confused about what you meant by "particular user".

Comment: I think this is off-topic, since it's about server administration and totally unrelated to programming.

Comment: You can use VirtualHost `_default_` for this purpose and use permanent redirect to the selected user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so this is what I ended up doing:

1. Copied `/var/cpanel/templates/apache2_4/main.default` to `/var/cpanel/templates/apache2_4/main.local`.
2. Edited the newly created copy to remove the default `VirtualHost` directives (I inserted  `[%- IF 0 %]` before line 344 and `[% END -%]` before line 385).
3. Edited `/var/cpanel/conf/apache/primary_virtual_hosts.conf` so that the name of the desired default host was specified for the desired IP address(es).
4. Ran `/scripts/rebuildhttpdconf`.
5. Manually verified `/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf`.
6. Gracefully restarted Apache.

Answer (score 1):

In general `VirtualHost`s matches the DNS entries, including wildcards.

Your situation seems to me like you are activating a new site and while the DNS is ready, the hosting isn't available yet, so you want to temporary display a specific `VirtualHost`.

I've had a similar problem in the past, and solved it by creating an `.htaccess` inside the default `VirtualHost` that redirects to the site I want.

This also has the benefit that the user is clearly viewing the real hostname in his browser.

I know that this isn't the solution you wanted, however I don't think there is any other way to accomplish this, because this has limited applications in normal usage (unusual behaviour).

Comment: Sadly, this won't work in our situation: the site served by the desired "default" VirtualHost determines the content that is to be served from the requested hostname—a redirect would lose this information (whilst one could forward it to the served website, e.g. via a querystring parameter, the arising UX would be unacceptable for this project).

Answer (score 0):

A bit old school I know, but url masking using a frame on your default page could be the easiest thing to do here?

Answer (score 0):

Create an .htaccess that proxies all requests back to localhost but on an internal port. Then add a Listen directive for the new port and a VirtualHost for that port that is the default you want.

I should mention that this is ugly, but I think it satisfies your needs.

Answer (score 0):

We currently use scheme where we first include *specific* default VHost config file, like so (that is before *any* VHost definitions):

```
Include conf.d/vhost.d/default.conf.first
Include conf.d/vhost.d/*.conf
```

This way VHost defined in `conf.d/vhost.d/default.conf.first` is always first.